# Controller not sending result with more than 1024 bytes data - Play Framework 2.4

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm using play java 2.4, but I also tried it in 2.5.
The controller is not sending any result when posted data size is over 1024 bytes.
I tried it with curl sending files of differents size.
Controller can read all data, but do not send any response when file size is over 1024 bytes.

routes :

```
POST    /message                      controllers.HomeController.rxmessage
```

HomeController.java :

```
public Result rxmessage() {
     Logger.warn("rxmessage");
     return ok("rxmessage ok\r\n");
 }
```

I test it with curl :

```
curl --header "Content-type: application/xml" --request POST -d @data.xml http://localhost:9000/message
```

When data.xml is under 1024 bytes :

```
~/Dev/Play/buffer-test$ curl --header "Content-type: application/xml" --request POST -d @data.xml http://localhost:9000/saetr
rxmessage ok
```

But when data.xml is over 1024 bytes, curl is waiting for an answer wich never arrive.

I tried to add in application.conf :

```
play.http.parser.maxMemoryBuffer = 256kB
parsers.Xml.maxLength=10240K
```

I tried BodyParser annotation :

```
@BodyParser.Of(value = BodyParser.Xml.class, maxLength = 10 * 1024)
public Result rxmessage() {
     Logger.warn("rxmessage");
     return ok("rxmessage ok\r\n");
 }
```

What am I doing wrong ?
Thanks for helping.

Comment: That is weird, isn't the default limit 100K?

Comment: I think you are configuring another parameter. You can try with `parsers.text.maxLength`, but @Anton is right. The default is 1024 * 100.

Comment: Maybe you should try with simple text and not xml for the first...

Answer (score 0):

I tried it on another computer and it's working.
I tried using curl from a virtual machine and it's working too.
So the problem seems to be curl but I can not say why. Weird.